# Mono SQLite with CF 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, mono, compact-framework

Is there a working way to use Mono SQLite with the Compact Framework 3.5?

Unfortunately I only have a .NET 4.0 Mono SQLite version and compiling it on my own also doesn't support .NET 3.5 as far as I can tell (and tried).

The issue I am running into is using EntitySpaces CF on an Android device and as he can't find my SQLite database, I am quite sure the standard SQLiteProvider does not support Android. The same source code is working on Windows 7 just fine, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: Sorry, where is the link between Mono.SQLite, Compact Framework 3.5, EntitySpaces CF and Android???? a) SQLite is supported by Android directly. b) SQLite offers CF and Windows CE comatible runtimes, no Mono.SQlite needed, c) Android can not run CF but Xamarin can. d) Xamarin can SQLite (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/)...The fact that the app runs on Win7 does not make any sense as agument for Android

Comment: The link is the application I have to write. I need to recompile EntitySpaces so that it works with Xamarin as it uses some references, that don't work fine with it. EntitySpaces provides a CF 3.5 version, that doesn't have any references on libraries that are not supported by Xamarin, so that's an 'easy' solution. Unfortunately there is no Mono SQLite version for CF 3.5 and using another SQLite library might be too much work. Could look into it though, didn't think of using Xamarin's SQLite.NET one. Unfortunately I can proceed with that project only on friday, so I am missing some information

Comment: I'm quite sure trying to downgrade a driver is _alot_ more work than downloading the SQLite driver for Compact Framework from `https://system.data.sqlite.org/`. It's also an ADO.NET implementation so you probably don't have to change much of your existing source code.